# How do I stop my rails application from returning a 304

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, disable-caching

I have a feeds controller that should **NEVER** return a `304`.

My render call looks like this ( where `json_feed_content` is a jsonp string );

```
render :text => jsonp_feed_content, :content_type => "application/json"
```

I have set caching to false in my production environment:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

I have a client script that constantly polls content from this feed, but most of the requests return `304` [Content Not Changed]. Is there a way to prevent my rails application from doing this?

Comment: is it doing a model/sql query? can you post a sample of the whole log?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add this to your controller:

```
#update last-modified so content is always fresh
headers['Last-Modified'] = Time.now.httpdate
```

There might be better ways, but this worked for me.